# Get distinct titles from product list with min and max price of that product title in django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset, distinct

I have list of products with same title but of different price.

This is my Product model:

```
class Product(BaseModel):
    title = models.ForeignKey(
        ProductTitle,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="product_title",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    price = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.00)])
    unit = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text="Standard measurement units.eg: kg, meter,etc..",
    )
    description = models.TextField(
        blank=True, null=True, help_text="Short Info about Product"
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, unique=True)
```

Say, I have 10 products of same title but with different price, and same goes for other products as well. Now i want to get single(distinct) product of particular title with Min and Max price for that product and so on. So, i should get say Orange with min and max price, apple with min and max price and so on.

I have tried some ways but its not working. Like in this query its giving me:

```
product_qs = (
            Product.objects.filter(is_deleted=False)
            .order_by("title__title")
            .distinct("title__title")
        )
p_list = product_qs.values_list("title", flat=True)

product_list = product_qs.filter(title__in=p_list).annotate(
            max_price=Max("price"), min_price=Min("price")
        )
```

```
NotImplementedError at /api/product/unique_product/
annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.
```

Can somebody help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Min, Max

Product.objects.values('title__title').annotate(min_val=Min('price'), max_val=Max('price')).order_by()
```

This will return :

A list of dictionaries, containing the `distinct title`, `min_price` and `max_price`

SQL Equivalent :

```
SELECT title, max(price) AS max_val, min(price) AS min_val FROM product_table GROUP_BY title;
```

values() for the `GROUP BY`, and `annotate()` for the MIN and MAX:

Comment: I want distinct product with min and max price. Your answer doesnot give distinct and it should also have min price and max price from its similar product

Comment: It actually returns a list of dictionaries, containing the distinct title, min_price and max_price. What output you are getting ?

Comment: Yes but my requirement is there should be single title say of pk 1, and it should have max_price and min_price. Your code gives product of title 1 with max, min and again product of title 1 with its max, min. There should be single in django called distinct product title.

Comment: Your code will give:        [{'title': 1, 'title__title': 'Gaurabproduct', 'min_val': 10.0, 'max_val': 10.0}, {'title': 1, 'title__title': 'Gaurabproduct', 'min_val': 30.0, 'max_val': 30.0}, {'title': 1, 'title__title': 'Gaurabproduct', 'min_val': 20.0, 'max_val': 20.0}]             so here Gaurabproduct has three different min/max price. I want single Gaurabproduct with min/max calculated from those three Gaurabproduct

Comment: ok got it, slight change in code as title is foreign key here, not string. updating ans wait

Comment: updated the answer, assuming `title__title` gives the actual string. should work now.

Comment: Nope. It doesnot give us distinct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236799/discussion-between-prakhar-and-gaurab-dawadi).